# ExpressCheckout.sln with masterpage

Tags: master-pages

How do I integrate the code of ExpressCheckout.sln in my source where I use a masterpage and asp. I tried to integrate it in WintipToys.sln from microsoft but it doesn't work.

Comment: No need anymore

Comment: Solved the problems in WingtipToys.sln